# Make NSButton blue (default)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How can I make an NSButton light up blue (ie. default) in Xcode 4? I've been trying various options in the interface builder but nothing seems to work. I've even tried setting the key equivalent to enter which also doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: After typing that I ran the app and setting the key equivalent does in fact work. It just doesn't reflect the change in the interface builder

Comment: Thanks for the solution—you should post that as an answer and then mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

swift：

```
@IBOutlet var testBtn: NSButton!
testBtn.keyEquivalent = "\r"
```

Comment: Also works using the designer UI - click on Key Equivalent entry and press enter key. Just tested on XCode 10.2.1