# NSButton: blue background

Tags: macos, appkit, nsbutton

I want to make my NSButton look like Xcode's commit button [image: Xcode commit button]

But there doesn't seem to be any way to easily change the background color for a NSButton. You have to change the 'border' to No, then set the button's backgroundColor, and set the 'attributedTitle' for the button to make the textColor white. But when I do this, the results don't look close at all:

[image]

The button doesn't have any shadow; the text doesn't look centered; it also doesn't support changing backgroundColor when the button is selected, like the button in Xcode does.

This should surely by easy to replicate, since I believe I've seen similar buttons all over the system.

Here is the NSButton subclass I wrote for this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.isBordered = false //Important
    self.layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
    self.layer?.cornerRadius = 6.0
    
    let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
    let fontColor = NSColor.white
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    self.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: self.title, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : fontColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle]) // to update text, have to update the attributeString's mutableString property
}
```

Would love to get pointers for where I'm going wrong with this. I would have thought a regular 'push' button with borders and shadow effect is what I need, but with a blue background, but that doesn't seem straigtforward from what I can see.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode set default button on enter when making a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850132/xcode-set-default-button-on-enter-when-making-a-form) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/MakingaButtontheDefaultButton.html

Comment: Or [Make NSButton blue (default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876764/make-nsbutton-blue-default?rq=1)

Comment: Already posted the answer for the solution I found. It's the same thing that @Marek H has pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

So found the 'easy' solution I was looking for: there's no need to do any NSButton layer tweaking. You just have to set the key equivalent to the 'return' key!

```
[self.editButton setKeyEquivalent: @"\r"];
```

This sets the button background color to blue, and works as I had hoped for. If you want some other background color, I guess you have to customize the button like above.

Comment: ..also these days we use properties in Obj-C, if we use it at all anymore.