# How can I have a blue style NSButton in macOS Cocoa?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am using this code below to make my button, the result is not the standard blue style apple button like the image, how can i change the setting of my NSButton to have this highlight?

```
myButton.bezelStyle = .rounded
myButton.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
```

The goal is to have this style:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make NSButton blue (default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876764/make-nsbutton-blue-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the key equivalent to `\r`:

[image]

Comment: That doesn’t set a style, that is just how the button is highlighted by the API to indicate the return keyEquivalent behavior.